# Selenium: Get link text for every link on a website

Tags: python, selenium

I  would like to fetch the linktext for a given website only and save them to a list. For example, in the following case I would like to save "Aeris Environmental" rather than "/Company/aeris-environmental"

```
<a href="/Company/aeris-environmental"> Aeris Environmental</a>
```

Using the following code I managed to retrieve the actual links but not the text.

```
elems = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a[@href]')
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

How can I achieve the same but with the text of a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
elems = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a')
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```